# Good xls exporter to generate excel sheets automatically with a few macros from any programming language?

Tags: java, php, python, macros, xls

We have a system which generates reports in XLS using Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer for smaller files and in case of huge files we just export them as CSVs.

We now want to export excel sheets which are multicolor etc. as a part of report generation, which in excel could be done through a few macros.

Is there any good exporter which generates the excel sheets with macros?(Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer cant do this) If it exists for PHP it would be amazing but if it exists for any other language, its fine we could interface it.

Comment: It should be able to run in the linux environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's your "excel sheets **with macros**" that is going to cause you all end of problems. If you're on a Windows platform, with Excel installed, then PHP's COM extension should allow you to do this. Otherwise, I'm nor aware of any PHP library which allows you to create macros... not even PHPExcel. I suspect the same will apply with most languages, other than perhaps those running with .Net (and possibly Mono).

However, do you really need macros to play with colour? Can't you do this more simply with styles, and perhaps conditional formatting?

PS. What's your definition of "huge"?

Comment: Formatting using Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer could be used but it has not proved to be a very good library to use.

Comment: Huge is something like half a million rows to a million rows, that is just for data transfer and archival.

Comment: @Stattrav - Have you looked at PHPExcel as an alternative to Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer (Note, I am the main developer)? This has a lot more styling options, and does support conditional formatting. It's slower and more memory-hungry than Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer, but there are techniques for reducing memory usage; and if this is being run from the command line, then execution speed should be less of a worry.

Comment: half a million rows to a million rows would require .xlsx rather than .xls if you wanted Excel (unless you wrote in the logic to split your data across multiple worksheets), so CSV is probably faster and more efficient if you don't need the formatting

Comment: Well, thank you for the reply and yeah, we need it as an automated export which has lower memory footprint and excessively fast as an user would click export and he would expect the exported data in a flick. So command line isnt really possible. Had it been a background process well that would help. I shall give PHPExcel and have a personal benchmark

Comment: @Stattrav - If you need both fast speed __and__ low memory usage, and don't mind BIFF8 .xls files only (where you'd need to be split your larger volumes of data across several worksheets), and are prepared to pay a small amount for it ($199 last I checked); then I'd recommend Ilia Alshanetsky's Excel extension (http://ilia.ws/archives/222-PHP-Excel-Extension.html), which is a wrapper for the commercial LibXL tool (http://www.libxl.com/)

Comment: Thank you very much, forwarding this to my boss so that he could decide upon this. (not the money but the BIFF8 .xls files). :)